# How do I query a content type with custom fields in the 'condition' statement

Tags: database

I need to query a content type both returning and filtering on conditions of custom fields.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query  ->fields('n',array('field_customfield1','field_customfield2'))
        ->condition('type', 'myContentType')
    ->condition('field_customfield3',$user->uid,'=')
    ->condition('field_customfield4',$anemailaddress,'=');
$foundrecord = $query->execute();
```

This doesn't seem to work. My issue is I can't figure out how to reference the custom fields in queries.

Any help GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You'd be better off using an [`EntityFieldQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) for this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'myContentType')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1) // in case you need it
  ->fieldCondition('field_customfield3', 'value', $user->uid)
  ->fieldCondition('field_customfield4', 'value', $anemailaddress);

$results = $query->execute();

if (isset($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node']));

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $customerfield1 = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_customerfield1');
    $first_value = $customerfield1[0]['value'];

    // etc...
  }
}
```

Even though it's more code, and more overhead, it has advantages over going into the database tables directly.

- You don't need to make the `JOIN`s yourself
- `EntityFieldQuery` respects node revisions, which will be harder to keep track of well using a custom query
- Your code is now portable if you decide to change the storage backend for fields to something other than MySQL (MongoDB for example).

Comment: Note that groupby is not permitted with EntityFieldQuery http://drupal.org/node/1565708

Answer (score 2):

Custom fields have their own separate tables.  Join them to the node by matching their entity_id to the nid, and then you can use them as conditions:

```
<?php
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
        ->fields('n',array('field_customfield1','field_customfield2'))
        ->condition('type', 'myContentType');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_customfield3','customfield3','n.nid = customfield3.entity_id');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_customfield4','customfield4','n.nid = customfield3.entity_id');
$query->condition('customfield3.field_customfield3_value',$user->uid,'=')
      ->condition('customfield4.field_customfield4_value',$anemailaddress,'=');
$foundrecord = $query->execute();
?>
```

Comment: `leftJoin()` doesn't return the query object so you can't use it in a chain unfortunately

Comment: I love this site :)  I'll edit the code

Comment: Johnathan, does your solution have the latest edits?

Comment: Yes, the only part I'm fuzzy on is if the last couple of conditions will work properly.