# Selecting nodes by content type and value of a custom field

Tags: entities, database

I need to select nodes (1) of a certain content type and (2) satisfying a test against a custom field's value. Pseudo-code would be:

```
select all nodes of type TYPE_X which are published and where MY_FIELD = 'x'
```

I tried that with the EntityFieldQuery suggested here: [How do I query a content type with custom fields in the 'condition' statement](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32170)
but Drupal/php crashes with "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of x bytes exhausted..."

So - what would be the correct code to use? I would appreciate a query which takes revisions into account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White screen of death: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54239/white-screen-of-death-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-x-bytes-exhausted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Views, you could do this:

1. Create a view, filter on node TYPE and node PUBLISHED
2. Create an argument/contextual filter using your CUSTOM FIELD
3. In Fields, select NID (and/or TITLE or whatever you want to work with in the node(s))

Preview the view, putting FILTERONTHIS in the arguments/contextual filter area.

Look at the SQL it generated in the Preview and cut/paste it into whatever you need, substituting FILTERONTHIS for a variable of your chosing. Or, save the view and then use [views_get_view_result()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result) to access the result.

Comment: Thanks Jimajamma. I did as you recommended (although I originally used direct filter method rather than contextual filter, but the resulting query was obviously quite similar). Now I would like to rewrite the query the Drupal way (as in: `$query = db_select('node', 'n')` etc.) My first attempts are erroneous and when I `dpm` them, they produce quite different statements.

Comment: The Views query is `SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_nick} field_data_field_nick ON node.nid = field_data_field_nick.entity_id AND (field_data_field_nick.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_nick.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (field_data_field_nick.field_nick_value = 'a10') )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('product')) )))`

Comment: Would it be too much if I asked for help in rewriting? This is my first Database API approach and I'm sure I could learn by example. Thanks.

Comment: I would be glad to if it were a D6 example as I have that down pat, but if you are on D7 (which I am suspecting) I won't be of much help because I am just now getting started with it.

Comment: but views_get_view_result() isn't that horrid...and is a lot easier to manage if you need to rework your queries at a later date...

Comment: I think I finally did it, but I'm now hitting another sort of problems. My result is: `$query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->leftJoin('field_data_field_nick', 'k', 'n.nid = k.entity_id');
  $query->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition('n.status', '1')
    ->condition('n.type', array('product'), 'IN')
    ->condition('k.field_nick_value', $id);`

Comment: The query works with static test arguments, so I assume it's correct. I'm accepting your answer as it pointed me to the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: glad to be of help!  I am learning a lot of D7 this way, too :)